# How can I identify global extremum given only the graph of the first derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

Suppose this is $f'(x)$:

[image]

And I am being asked if $f(x)$ has global extremum.

Since the endpoints are open, there can't be a global extremum there. So now I only have to check for B, D and F.

But without any numbers, I feel like I can't really check verify those points.

For example, B and E are clearly a local minimums, but how can I tell which one is "lower" in $f(x)$? And even more importantly, even if I figure that out, how could I verify that it really is the *lowest* $f(x)$ can be?

D is the only local maximum so at least I don't need to compare it with any other critical point, but I still can't guarantee that $f(D)$ is the highest it can get.

I was thinking that I could reason that the "area inside the curve" is larger/smaller at certain intervals so that would allow me to compare critical points, but that's related to integration I think and beyond the scope of my homework, so I feel there is something more fundamental that I am missing here.

Comment: I would suggest to include the endpoints, even if just for figuring out if the inner points really are global extrema or not. If you include the endpoints, then you know that global min and Max exist, and you just have to figure out *where* they are (either A,B,D,F, or G). The only real way I can see how  to do that is (as you say) looking at the area below the derivative, i.e., "integrating". From the graph it's quite plausible that A and G have strictly lower value of f than D, so that will be the global max.

Answer (score 1):

For this, we can use the first derivative test. Essentially, if the graph of $f'(x)$ goes from positive to negative at a point, that point is a maximum. Points B and F go from negative to positive, so they can't be maximums. Point D, however, goes from positive to negative. Therefore, point D is your global maximum.

Comment: Doesn't that test only prove locals? $f(D)$ is certainly a local max, but how can you guarantee that it really is the highest value $f(x)$ can have just from this graph?

Comment: @ZolTunKul Yes, you're correct. However, under the scope of your homework (as you say in the question), integration has not yet been taught in your course and should not be applied to this question. Because you cannot otherwise check the endpoints and the endpoints are not included, they should be ignored, leaving the only other possible option -- D.